# Mathematical explanation for geometric probability formulas

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a dartboard. Some of its portion is painted red. I throw a dart at it. Now, I want to calculate the probability that my dart hits the red area. I simply divide the area of the painted region with the total area of the dartboard.

My question is how can we be sure that this process of calculating probability using areas actually give the right answerer? Intuitively, this seems very correct. But is there any mathematical explanation to the formulas that we use in geometric probability?

Comment: It probably does not give the correct answer, unless your dart throws are uniformly distributed across the dartboard.  And that is a strong assumption.

Comment: Please define "the right answer" here. Two steps are involved, one from a real-life situation to a mathematical model and the other from a mathematical model to mathematical results. The accuracy of the latter is rather clear-cut but the accuracy of the former is a much murkier matter...

Comment: If you paint the dartboard to look like the BMW logo, but with red quadrants instead of blue, and if you assume you are as likely to miss your point of aim to the left as to the right, with the same distribution of vertical error on both sides, then (red area)/(total area) is plausible. (The answer is 1/2.) But these assumptions about how people "miss" are still unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the answers from what we refer to as "geometric probability" are fundamentally limits of the ratio of various areas, which is why it is considered "continuous" - there are technically an infinite number of possible outcomes. But because areas are usually calculable, our answer is just as accurate as answers found using traditional discrete probability.